# What is the meaning of the phrase "you don't have it"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

The sentence goes, "You douchebags don't have it"

It was said by a woman who complained about guys that were two-timing and they should fess up to their women.

Comment: It means the guys don’t possess whatever “it” refers to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It likely refers to the guys not "having what it takes" either to be a (good) man or to be an honest man.